# Delete hidden rows in loop works only in first run

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is:

1. Open file named Warranty Upsell Q420 for .xlsm on my pc
2. Filter Data on Sheet named ("Endkunden")
3. Delete hidden rows
4. Save file with initial name + the item name from array.

Those steps should be done six times with the items in the array, which i created from a range.

My Problem:

Hidden rows are only deleted in the first file. Every other file still has the initial Data in Sheet("Endkunden"). Everything else works fine, all six files are created.

I tried to reduce the code as much as possible. Hopefully someone is able to help!

```
Dim DirArray As Variant
        Dim xRow As Range
        Dim xRg As Range
        Dim xRows As Range
        Dim yRow As Range
        Dim yRg As Range
        Dim yRows As Range
        Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
        Dim sourceFileName As String
        
        'fill array with values from a range'
        
        DirArray = tgt.Range("A1:A" & lastRowtgt).Value
        
        
       Dim item As Variant
       
       For Each item In DirArray
          
        'Open file which is going to be filtered and then saved with initial name + item name'
        
        sourceFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Warranty Upsell Q420 for .xlsm"
        
        Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sourceFileName)
        
        wbTemplate.Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 2).Value = item
        
        'Filter No.1'
        
        Dim sReseller As String
             
        sReseller = wbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview").Cells(4, 2)
        wbTemplate.Worksheets("Endkunden").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B32456").AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B32456").AutoFilter 1, sReseller
        
        wbTemplate.Sheets("Endkunden").Range("B2:B32456").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Filter").Range("F3")
        wbTemplate.Sheets("Endkunden").Range("B2:B32456").Copy
        wbTemplate.Sheets("Filter").Range("F3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     
     
        'Delete hidden rows'
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xRows = Intersect(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Endkunden").Range("A:A").EntireRow, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Endkunden").UsedRange)
        If xRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            For Each xRow In xRows.Columns(1).Cells
                If xRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
                    If xRg Is Nothing Then
                        Set xRg = xRow
                    Else
                        Set xRg = Union(xRg, xRow)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
                            xRg.EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                MsgBox "No hidden rows found"
            End If
            
        
        'Save with different name'
        
        wbTemplate.SaveAs (Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Warranty Upsell Q420 for " & item & ".xlsm")
        wbTemplate.Close
          
        Next item
```

Comment: What I see is that you don't reset xRg , so for the second iteration it still contain the rows of the first iteration. However, using `Union` should give a runtime error in that case - do you have the infamous `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Replace `On Error Resume Next` with `Set xRg = Nothing`. Don't use it until you [learn how to use it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Yes I'm in the middle of the learning stage:)